# Which files in a firefox profiles are important for a profile?

Tags: firefox, profile

When you start a new firefox profile, firefox instantly creates a lot of files in the profile. Still you can say, that the current state does not need any of the files in the profile, as they will be created again.

Some files are redundant on purpose (like web cache), others may be rebuild from files containing the actual data (i.e. sqlite database journals).
Some others cannot be rebuild easily once the profile was used, like places.db.

Now I would like to create a few profiles for single webapps (like chrome appmode, but with a bit more customization). For this, I want to create a minimal template profile i.e. with customizations of UI elements and some smaller addons. Then I want to strip all files which will be created again on the next start from the template.
Next I like to use the created profiles, but i.e. remove indexeddb and localstorage afterwards, so the next user of the webapp doesn't inherit the session of the previous one.

For this, I am researching which files can be stripped (automatically) from a profile without breaking things. Or better a whitelist of needed files. Is there any reference (other than the source code) for the stuff which is created in new profiles and which files are recreated when they are missing and which files can break a profile?

Comment: Hello @allo, have you got this information anyhow? Thank you very much!

Comment: No and I doubt that there really is a full list. But any helpful ressources would be a good start. The other way is testing which files must be copied for the information which should be kept between sessions. But there is always a risk of dependencies which cannot be seen directly, like between the places database and the (new) favicon database.